# Prolog array in rules and operation

Tags: prolog

I have a little problem with define facts and search in array in Prolog. I dont know, how add to rule my array and result of it.

Ok, need some like this:

```
% John is allergic to fish and milk.
isAllergic(john, [fish, milk]).

% food shark has allergen fish and john cant eat it and drink milk
allergen(shark, fish).
allergen(milk, milk).

%I need list of food, what person (john) can eat.
foodForPerson(F,C):- isAllergic(F, X), allergen(X,C).
```

And then I call FoodForPerson(john,X), but result is false. I think, that problem is in array. 
Result should be X=milk, X=shark.

Comment: How to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You don't need `element/2`. Prolog already has `member/2`, *e.g.*, `member(b, [a,b,c])` is true. And per Boris' comment, read the documentation on how to ask a good question. You need to better describe specifically what you want your code to do and what it actually does. Showing examples helps.

Comment: If `isAllergic(john, [fish, milk])` is true, how is it that john can drink milk, per your code comment? This code is very confusing. It's quite unclear what your facts and predicates really mean.

Comment: sorry, my mistake! Of course he cant drink milk, sorry :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `member/2` call to get an element out of an array:

```
foodForPerson(F,C) :-
    isAllergic(F, Xs),
    members(X,Xs),
    allergen(X,C).
```

Although a better way to represent this is using facts, instead of lists, thus:

```
isAllergic(john, fish).
isAllergic(john, milk).
```

In that case your proposed predicate would have worked. And furthermore it's easy to `assert` and `retract` single facts. Or combine different libariries how each know something about John.

**Edit**

In case you wish to use a list for `allergen` as well, you can make use of member twice:

```
isAllergic(john, [fish, milk]).

allergen(sharkWitHPotato, [fish, potato]).

foodForPerson(F,X) :-
    isAllergic(F, As),
    allergen(X,Cs),
    member(A,As),
    member(A,Cs).
```

Note that in your comment, you swapped the arguments of `allergen` I guess?

But this can result in listing the same tuple `john,sharkWitHPotato` multiple times.

Comment: thanks, it is what I want. and when I have in allergen array - allergen(sharkWitHPotato, [fish, potato]) ? How solve this?

Comment: @Felix: did you swap the arguments of `allergen/2`? Now you probably want to return `sharkWitHPotato`?

Comment: yeah, I want.. and function members is correct or is same as member?

Comment: @Felix: what do you mean with *function members*? Prolog has no such thing as functions. It works with *predicates* and *terms*. Sometimes *predicates* are converted to *terms* to allow higher order calls.

Comment: foodForPerson(F,X) :-
    isAllergic(F, As),
    allergen(X,Cs),
    members(A,As),
    member(A,Cs). becouse SWI-Prolog dont know "members"

Comment: @Felix: indeed, that was a typo, sorry.